# How to remove blank spaces on Hiding rows in Table View Cell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

i was able to hide row on Table View Cell by using this code

```
cell.hidden = YES;
```

the problem is it gives blank spaces (show on the picture).

[image: screen shot]

Is there any way on eliminating this blank spaces?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the correct height for the cell in the UITableViewDelegate.

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == someIndex) {
        return 0.0f;
    }

    return 65.0f;
}
```

Better would be to not have the cell in tabelview at all.